# Does Office 365 offer a floating / network licensing model?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing

Such that only up to N licenses can be shared between 5 x N users on different computers at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no floating licence model AFAIK. But you can maybe use terminal services from a host terminal server with sufficient licenses to cover usage, or Microsoft cloud-hosted services (like Office 365 Business Essentials - which doesn't, however, include desktop versions)?

Answer (score 0):

As @sarlacii said, there is no floating license model. Taking in consideration that Office365 is a cloud service, how would it work? Each time you are creating a user and assigning a license to the user, there are accounts created in their AD and mailboxes created on exchange. It would be really bad for their business model if it worked like you want it to.